# Help with example RSA problem

Tags: rsa

While learning about RSA, I found [this example problem](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC3/crypto/node14.html). The answer is supposed to be "a 4-digit number that is a pattern of digits." I have computed it to be 16657 twice.

> OK, now to see if you understand the RSA decryption algorithm, suppose you are person A, and you have chosen as your two primes $p = 97$ and $q = 173$, and you have chosen $e = 5$. Thus you told B that $N = 16781$ (which is just $pq$) and you told him that $e = 5$.
>
> He encodes a message (a number) for you and tells you that the encoding is 5347. Can you figure out the original message? Hint--well, not really a hint, but a check of your final answer: it is a four-digit number that is a pattern of digits.

I have failed to decode this to a 4-digit number. What am I doing wrong?

```
p = 97
q = 173
N = 16781
dp = 16512 = (p-1)(q-1)
e = 5
d = ?
C = 5347
M = ?
```

I computed d = 6605 since that seems to be the smallest value of d possible for:

```
ed = 1(mod (p-1)(q-1))
5d = 1(mod 96 * 172)
5d = 1(mod 16512)
# I need a multiplier for 16512 that when added to 1 yields a number that
# ends in a 5 or a 0 so it will evenly divide by e=5
# 1 + 2 times dp will yield a number that ends in a 5
d = 6605
```

Now I need to compute `M = C^d(mod N)`:

```
M = C^d(mod 16781)

    5347^6605(mod 16781)

6605 = 4096 + 2048 + 256 + 128 + 64 + 8 + 4 + 1

5347^1   (mod 16781)    = 5347
5347^2   (mod 16781)    = 12366   (not included in final math)
5347^4   (mod 16781)    = 9484
5347^8   (mod 16781)    = 96
5347^64  (mod 16781)    = 389
5347^128 (mod 16781)    = 292
5347^256 (mod 16781)    = 1359
5347^1024(mod 16781)    = 3105
5347^2048(mod 16781)    = 8731
5347^4096(mod 16781)    = 11059

5347^6605(mod 16781)    = 16657
```

I've also computed the same result in Excel by reproducing the same table above one power at a time for 6605 rows.

Update: It turns out to have been a mistake. The original author [corrected the problem](http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/RSA.pdf), but not before the error was copied across the internet.

Comment: I suspect the problem is with `d`.

Comment: Your $d$ is OK, even if you did not derive it using a standard method, like the [extended Euclidian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). I concur with [poncho's answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8793/555). I tried with 5347 as an octal number, that does not work either. And that's not the intend [here](http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC3/rsa.pdf), which is just wrong.

Comment: @fgrieu, poncho: [Sorry to put this here] Would either of you be available for some short term consulting? I need a simplistic crypto design reviewed. I tried e-mailing Françous at two googled e-mail addresses, but I'm not sure if I got them right.

Comment: @poncho: same question. I can't figure out if stack exchange supports private messages

Comment: Ah, [no private messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user) for stack exchange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't appear to have done anything wrong; you can double check your result by computing:

> $16657^5 \bmod 16781$

and find that it is indeed 5347; that is, 16657 is the number that, when encoded with the public key, results in the value you were given.

I suspect that moral of this story is that random examples on the internet might be worth just as much as you pay for them.

Comment: What bothers me is that this example was lifted and used in other places as well including a [kids crypto competition](http://science.holeintheground.net/events/Cryptography/description.html).

Comment: Also, the original link is cited in many places on the internet. I think most readers simply skip the exercise.